# Is this analytic continuation even possible?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I'm pretty sure all Dirichlet L-Functions can be analytically continued to the whole plane, and the analytic continuation in question would be a function similar to the Euler Product of a regular L-Function, except instead of a product with a random character inside, its only a product over primes that are congruent to a number a (mod b). The presence of a character inside the product is not of concern at all. Is it possible to analytically continue this function? I'm sure it would be extremely difficult to do so, so any information at all would be wonderful.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand exactly what you are asking (at least it is to me).

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page about Dirichlet L-functions, which has the meromorphic (not analytic) continuation and Euler product formula, maybe it would help you to state your question a little clearer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function

Comment: Here is a little clarification, i hope. For starters, here is an example of a function im talking about: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product+Prime%5Bn%5D%5Es%2F%28Prime%5Bn%5D%5Es-1%29 except, for example, i want to consider primes congruent to 3 modulo 7. Its not an L-function. My question though, can it be analytically continued to the left half of the plane?